# Iframe Not Working in IE11

Tags: visualforce, internet-explorer

I have a VF page which contains an iFrame as shown below.

```
<apex:page controller="SomeController" action="{!callWebService}" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:iframe src="data:application/pdf;content-disposition:attachment;base64,{!pdfString}" width="100%" height="600"/>
```

pdfString is the string i am getting from the web service callout response as below.

```
pdfString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(response.getBodyasBlob());
```

I am able to view the PDF in Chrome and FireFox, but in IE i am getting a blank white screen. Can some one please help me resolve this issue?